# WYSIWYG shortcode

Tags: magento-enterprise, rwd-theme

I have created a static block to put on my tab content for my product details page. 
I have WYSIWYG editor to one of my field in my product (ex: delivery)

I have used this code below:

```
{{block type="cms/block" block_id="your_block_id"}}
```

But it doesn't work. After placing the code this what I get

[image]

[image]

Please help

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default you cannot add `cms` directives to the product attributes.
I mean you can, but they won't get parsed.
If you want to show them correctly you need to print the value as follows.
Let's say the attribute code is `delivery`.

Do this:

```
<?php
$value = $_product->getDelivery();
$processor = Mage::getModel((string)Mage::getConfig()->getNode(Mage_Cms_Helper_Data::XML_NODE_BLOCK_TEMPLATE_FILTER)));
$processedValue = $processor->filter($value);
?>
<?php echo $processedValue;?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to have CMS blocks render as product attribute values. If you do want the CMS block content as the attribute value why don't you just copy the block's content into that attribute?

If you do want to use a static block you could follow something like [this.](http://www.milessebesta.com/web-design/magento-use-custom-product-attributes-to-add-cms-static-block-to-product-page/)

OR

You could write in code like this to get static block content:

```
$cmsStatic = $product->getDelivery()
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockID($cmsstatic)->tohtml();
```

The Value in Delivery attribute would be the block id of the CMS block.